# When matching, do you create a variable on the fly in the case statement?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm looking at this scala code and confused where the variable `partitionedData` is coming from in the `case Some(partitionedData)` statement:

```
private def dispatchSerializedData(messages: Seq[KeyedMessage[K,Message]]): Seq[KeyedMessage[K, Message]] = {
    val partitionedDataOpt = partitionAndCollate(messages)
    partitionedDataOpt match {
      case Some(partitionedData) =>
        val failedProduceRequests = new ArrayBuffer[KeyedMessage[K,Message]]
        try {
          for ((brokerid, messagesPerBrokerMap) <- partitionedData) {
            if (logger.isTraceEnabled)
              messagesPerBrokerMap.foreach(partitionAndEvent =>
                trace("Handling event for Topic: %s, Broker: %d, Partitions: %s".format(partitionAndEvent._1, brokerid, partitionAndEvent._2)))
            val messageSetPerBroker = groupMessagesToSet(messagesPerBrokerMap)

            val failedTopicPartitions = send(brokerid, messageSetPerBroker)
            failedTopicPartitions.foreach(topicPartition => {
              messagesPerBrokerMap.get(topicPartition) match {
                case Some(data) => failedProduceRequests.appendAll(data)
                case None => // nothing
              }
            })
          }
        } catch {
          case t: Throwable => error("Failed to send messages", t)
        }
        failedProduceRequests
      case None => // all produce requests failed
        messages
    }
  }
```

During a match, do you create a variable on the fly?  is it equal to partitionedDataOpt ?

Comment: Checkout this blog post on pattern matching and `unapply` which is where your partionedData is coming from http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`partitionedDataOpt` is an `Option` and can be either a `Some(value)` or a `None` (both are subtypes of `Option`)

If `partitionedDataOpt` is a `Some` Option, it wraps the actual value inside, and the pattern matching marks `partitionedData` as the value contained in the option. In that case you can name it however you want, and it is local to the matched case.

> During a match, do you create a variable on the fly?

You can say so, I think `partitionedData` can be seen as a local val scoped in the `case` clause

> is it equal to partitionedDataOpt ?

You can say it's equal to `partitionedDataOpt.get` *if* partitionedDataOpt has a value (e.g. a `Some`)

It is not unique to `Options` by the way `Some` and `None` are simply case classes extending `Option` ([source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L294))

```
/** Class `Some[A]` represents existing values of type
 *  `A`.
 *
 *  @author  Martin Odersky
 *  @version 1.0, 16/07/2003
 */
final case class Some[+A](x: A) extends Option[A] {
  def isEmpty = false
  def get = x
}


/** This case object represents non-existent values.
 *
 *  @author  Martin Odersky
 *  @version 1.0, 16/07/2003
 */
case object None extends Option[Nothing] {
  def isEmpty = true
  def get = throw new NoSuchElementException("None.get")
}
```